# how to insert ASP.NEt3.5 ajaxtoolkit Editor control text to MSSQl2005 database 

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

how to insert ASP.NEt3.5 ajaxtoolkit Editor control text to MSSQl2005 database ..

Answer (score 0):

put the control on the page. Say your id is Editor1. Then in code behind, use Editor1.Content to get the text you have inside the edior. Pass it in your parameter. One thing if you are inserting long text, use text as field in the database. Or nvarchar(max) so as to hold html characters. IF you receieve error potentially dangerous request, set the validaterequest to false.